# What GCP permissions are required for PubsubIO

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

What GCP permissions are required for reading from a Cloud Pub/Sub subscription with class [PubsubIO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.27.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/pubsub/PubsubIO.html) ?

I had `pubsub.subscriptions.consume`, but that does not seem enough.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using google cloud dataflow, the dataflow service account should contain all the permissions required for reading from Pubsub. You can view the list of policies associated with the service account using command `gcloud iam roles describe roles/dataflow.serviceAgent`.